# Clicking sound when doing FFT.forwardTransform()

Tags: tarsosdsp

I'm trying to visualize the FFT of a sound while listening to it using the TarsosDSP library. However, when listening to it, there is a loud clicking noise that's being played and I can't seem to understand where this is coming from. This is happening on a PC.

With all things staying the same in my code, I've narrowed it down to the FFT.forwardTransform() function.

Here's the essential wiring of my application:

Application.java:

```java
            InputStream audioStreasm = getClass().getResourceAsStream(selectedSound);
            InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(audioStreasm);
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn);

            JVMAudioInputStream audioStream = new JVMAudioInputStream(audioInputStream);
            // create a new dispatcher
            dispatcher = new AudioDispatcher(audioStream, bufferSize, overlap);
            dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(new FFTProcessor(fftSize, sampleRate));
            dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(new AudioPlayer(audioStream.getFormat()));

            // run the dispatcher (on a new thread).
            new Thread(dispatcher, "Audio dispatching").start();
```

The file is a 1.85Mb wav file. 
bufferSize is 1536
sampleRate is 44100

And FFTProcessor.java essentially looks like this:

```java
public class FFTProcessor implements AudioProcessor {
    private int sampleRate;
    private FFT fft;
    private float[] amplitudes;

    public FFTProcessor(int fftSize, int sampleRate) {
        this.sampleRate = sampleRate;
        fft = new FFT(fftSize);
        amplitudes = new float[fftSize];
    }

     @Override
     public boolean process(AudioEvent audioEvent) {
        float[] audioBuffer = audioEvent.getFloatBuffer();
        fft.forwardTransform(audioBuffer);
        fft.modulus(audioBuffer, amplitudes);

        return true;
     }
}
```

I've tried limiting executions by introducing a form of throttling, thinking it might help. 
I also tried not using buffered input, in case there's a buffer underrun.

But the problem is still present and I'm starting to run out of ideas on what to try next.

Appreciate any pointers, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a known issue, as per: https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP/issues/90

The following modification to the above code fixes the issue of the sound clicking.

```java
dispatcher = new AudioDispatcher(audioStream, (int) audioStream.getFrameLength() - 2, overlap);
```

However now, the FFT processor seems to be having problems. I'll have to investigate further.

Cheers!